# the accuracy grid search gave me for image classification (using feature extraction with vgg16 and xgboost) was wrong?

Tags: neural-networks, image-processing, transfer-learning

so I'm somewhat a beginner at machine learning.

for an image classification problem, I used feature extraction using vgg16 and gave the features to xgboost model as input. then used grid search to get better results. so according to grid search the best accuracy was 80%. but after I commented the grid search part and input the same hyperparameters grid search gave me in xgboost model, I got 72% accuracy. why?

last part of code code with grid search:

```
x_train, x_test = x_train/255.0, x_test/255.0
IMAGE_SIZE=[224,224]
model = VGG16(input_shape=IMAGE_SIZE+[3],weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

feature_extractor = model.predict(x_train)
features = feature_extractor.reshape(feature_extractor.shape[0], -1)

from xgboost import XGBClassifier
classifier = XGBClassifier()
classifier.fit(features, y_train)
x_test_feature = model.predict(x_test)
x_test_features = x_test_feature.reshape(x_test_feature.shape[0], -1)
predict = classifier.predict(x_test_features)

from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
parameters = [{'gamma': [0, 1, 5],
               'learning_rate': [0.1, 0.9, 0.08, 0.7, 0.06, 0.5, 0.04, 0.3, 0.02, 0.01],
               'subsample': [0.8, 0.9, 1],
               'colsample_bytree': [0.8, 0.9, 1]
              }]
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator = classifier,
                           param_grid = parameters,
                           scoring = 'accuracy',
                           cv = 5)
grid_search.fit(features, y_train)
print("Best Accuracy: ", grid_search.best_score_)
print("Best Parameters: ", grid_search.best_params_)
```

after that, I just changed it to this:

```
x_train, x_test = x_train/255.0, x_test/255.0
IMAGE_SIZE=[224,224]
model = VGG16(input_shape=IMAGE_SIZE+[3],weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

feature_extractor = model.predict(x_train)
features = feature_extractor.reshape(feature_extractor.shape[0], -1)

from xgboost import XGBClassifier

**#change here**
classifier = XGBClassifier(gamma=0, colsample_bytree=1, subsample=0.9, learning_rate=0.7)

classifier.fit(features, y_train)
x_test_feature = model.predict(x_test)
x_test_features = x_test_feature.reshape(x_test_feature.shape[0], -1)
predict = classifier.predict(x_test_features)

from sklearn import metrics
print("Accuracy: ", metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, predict))
```

Comment: You compare ``grid_search.best_score`` against ``metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, predict)``. Question you need to ask yourself, is ``y_test`` used anywhere when calling ``grid_search``?

Comment: @runr it's not. now that u mention it, Im not sure how grid search is calculating accuracy. maybe it's splitting the data in classifier? if this is true, I assume 72% is more accurate here?

Comment: It's probably getting the accuracy from the 5-fold cross validation. (Train on 4 splits, accuracy measure on the 5th, and return some average). So depending on the splits and size of the sample, the accuracy measure can vary. I haven't analyzed your code, but it feels to me like what you're doing is correct. You split the data into ``train`` and ``holdout`` samples. On the ``train`` sample, you perform a CV grid search which uses out of sample predictions for the choice of hyperparameter. You then compare the performance on the ``holdout`` dataset that wasn't used anywhere (your ``y_test``)

Comment: This approach is similar to typical model selection approaches, see, e.g., [ESLR](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/printings/ESLII_print12_toc.pdf) page 222 (241 of the PDF, 222 in print), where the authors discuss the common train/validation/holdout approaches and their shortcomings